# Can ECTool kick off Hudson Jobs?

Tags: interop, hudson, hudson-plugins, electric-cloud

I am looking for a way to run Hudson jobs from an Electric Commander pipeline, I know it doesn't make much sense. We are migrating from a Hudson box to Electric Commander and cannot migrate all of the jobs immediately. I have read that ECTool can run Hudson jobs and get the info back within the same pipeline

http://www.electric-cloud.com/blog/2012/05/01/pushing-information-from-external-systems-into-electriccommander/

I can't find what exactly I need to do to kick it off though any tips?

Thanks

Additional Info

I have been studying http://docs.electric-cloud.com/commander_doc/4_2/Help_4_2_3/usingapi.htm and also playing around in the EC command line, I think I need to make a bash file to call the Hudson jobs but I am not sure where to start

Comment: Can you share what you've tried thus far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jenkins plugin at http://plugins.electric-cloud.com/ will work for Hudson as well, I didn't know that